# Missing values in PowerBI slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem in my cube with a dimension value as a slicer or a filter. It has no and name and I want to slice on name, but some of the values are missing. It is the same problem if I use no. If I use no as a filter and use advanced filter to search for the specific no the data works, but the slicer for name is still empty. The strange thing is that I can see the no and name fine in the data area, just not in the filter or if I use a slicer.

I have the same problem in PowerBI desktop and in the online version.

Edited:

I have several facts using the same dimensions. I have found that a disabling a specific relationship from a fact one of the dimensions makes the problem disappear. The number of values in the slicer are a bit too many, but at least now it doesn't exclude some of the values I can see. The only problem is that I need the relationship. I have checked if there should be a problem with the values for the relationship such as missing or null values, all the values are there.

Comment: Do you have any sample data that could be used to recreate what you're seeing?

Comment: Sadly it is part of a larger project, but I will see if I can come up with something. The dimension in question has around 80k rows but with the filters it is down to around 100 that is shown in the data area. I have seen the filter load more rows than that, so the number of results is not the problem. I found that some filters make them disappear in the slicer, but still remain in the data area. I'm mostly wondering if anyone has seen something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and adding the problematic fact table again **solved** the problem.

It was quite hard to find out what was causing the problem to begin with. I went about it by first creating a minimal cube to make sure that the core data was correct. After verifying that, I opened the problematic cube and starting removing facts and dimensions until the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found the solution for my dashboard: when you go to the options of the X axis there is a Start and End box. In my End box there was a number, which caused the last value to disappear. When I removed this number (and Auto appeared), my graph was complete again.

[image]